# How to hold up a script until a slurm job (start with srun) is completely finished?

Tags: cluster-computing, slurm

I am running a job array with SLURM, with the following job array script (that I run with `sbatch job_array_script.sh [args]`:

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH ... other options ...

#SBATCH --array=0-1000%200

srun ./job_slurm_script.py $1 $2 $3 $4

echo 'open' > status_file.txt
```

To explain, I want `job_slurm_script.py` to be run as an array job 1000 times with 200 tasks maximum in parallel.  And when **all** of those are done, I want to write 'open' to `status_file.txt`. This is because in reality I have more than 10,000 jobs, and this is above my cluster's MaxSubmissionLimit, so I need to split it into smaller chunks (at 1000-element job arrays) and run them one after the other (only when the previous one is finished).

However, for this to work, the echo statement can only trigger once the entire job array is finished (outside of this, I have a loop which checks `status_file.txt` so see if the job is finished, i.e when the contents are the string 'open').

Up to now I thought that `srun` holds the script up until the whole job array is finished. However, sometimes `srun` "returns" and the script goes to the echo statement before the jobs are finished, so all the subsequent jobs bounce off the cluster since it goes above the submission limit.

So how do I make `srun` "hold up" until the whole job array is finished?

Comment: Each task of the job array is independent, so srun can not affect it. You could use dependencies to start a job once all the array steps have finished

Comment: what are dependencies in this context?

Comment: dependencies will prevent a job to start until the job that it depends on has finished

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can add the flag `--wait` to [sbatch](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html).

Check the manual page of [sbatch](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html) for information about `--wait`.

Comment: This is not a helpful answer, you just link to the general documentation opposed to `sbatch` specifically: https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html

Comment: @DylanMadisetti you can [suggest an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49509245/edit) to improve posts!

Answer (score 8):

You can use `--wait` option in `sbatch` in combination with `wait` in bash to send jobs off to the cluster, pause script execution until those are complete, and then continue. E.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
date

for((i=0; i<5; i++)); do
    sbatch -W --wrap='echo "hello from $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID"; sleep 10' &
done;
wait

date
echo "I am finished"
```

Answer (score 0):

0-1000%200 means 200 simultaneous jobs use %1 instead.

Answer (score -5):

You can use the `wait` bash command. It will wait until whatever lines of code above are finished. Thus you script should look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH ... other options ...

#SBATCH --array=0-1000%200

srun ./job_slurm_script.py $1 $2 $3 $4

wait

echo 'open' > status_file.txt
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work and gives the same problem as before.

Comment: What version of SLURM are you running and on what kind of system?

Comment: slurm 17.02.7. Also what do you mean by system. From what I've seen, srun doesn't *immediately* skip past onto the next command. Usually what seems to happen is that srun holds/waits for quite a while. But something then happens to make it skip past. I'm not sure what, although one thing I suspect is that this happens when all the array job tasks are pending.

Comment: This would be the correct answer for the question "how do I wait for a local background process to finish" but that's not what is being asked here.