# How to add sbatch options such as --wait in a snakemake file

Tags: snakemake

I am unsure where I add the `--wait` sbatch option when using snakemake. I tried to add it to the snakemake command itself but I get the following error:

```
Error submitting jobscript (exit code 1):
Submitted batch job 5389577
```

Any help would be appriciated.

My snakemake command is as follows:

```
snakemake --latency-wait 60 --rerun-incomplete --keep-going --jobs 99 --cluster-status 'python /home/lamma/faststorage/scripts/slurm-status.py' --cluster 'sbatch  -t {cluster.time} --mem={cluster.mem} --cpus-per-task={cluster.c} --error={cluster.error}  --job-name={cluster.name} --output={cluster.output} --wait' --cluster-config bacterial-hybrid-assembly-config.json --configfile yaml-config-files/test_experiment3.yaml --snakefile bacterial-hybrid-assembly.smk
```

Comment: What are you trying to wait for? And Why?

Comment: I am calling another pipeline in a rule but snakemake tried to move onto the next rule before the pipeline in the previous rule has finished running so I get missingoutput errors. This is [my post about that issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59630183/calling-another-pipeline-within-a-snakefile-result-in-mising-output-errors/59633049?noredirect=1#comment105446846_59633049)

Answer (score 0):

Adding `--parsable` flag to `sbatch` command will allow `--cluster-status` script to properly parse job IDs. Relevant sources: [1](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/additional_features.html#using-cluster-status), [2](https://bitbucket.org/snakemake/snakemake/issues/638/external-job-id-not-correctly-retrieved-in#comment-40649017).

```
'sbatch  -t {cluster.time} --mem={cluster.mem} --cpus-per-task={cluster.c} --error={cluster.error}  --job-name={cluster.name} --output={cluster.output} --wait --parsable'
```